# Cannot use SQL Lead function correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 4 columns: date, event_name, video_id and user_id.

I need to write a query that will return the number of users who viewed at least one video in a given day and the number of those users who returned the next day to view at least one video. The video_play event signifies that a video was played by a user.

Here's some sample data upon which I need to base my query:

```
date            event_name      video_id    user_id
2018-01-01      video_play      51651561651 989189198
2018-01-01      video_play      98121651656 561884864
2018-01-01      video_play      78918918918 561884864
2018-01-01      create_video    32156541355 153215651
2018-01-01      create_video    87351531311 232135135
2018-01-02      create_video    51651561651 489846581
2018-01-02      video_play      12315315352 561884864
2018-01-02      create_video    32156541355 321351351
2018-01-02      create_video    87351531311 231513515
2018-01-02      video_play      98191891894 615616516
```

This is how the output should look:

```
date        users_view_videos   users_view_next_day
2018-01-01  2                   1
2018-01-02  2                   0
```

This query completes the first half of the querying task, but I cannot figure out the second half:

```
with t1 as
(select date,
count(distinct user_id) as users_view_next_day
from clickstream_videos
WHERE event_name = 'video_play'
group by 1)

select clickstream_videos.date, 
count(distinct user_id) as users_view_videos,
lead(users_view_next_day, 1) over(order by clickstream_videos.date) 
from clickstream_videos
join t1
on clickstream_videos.date = t1.date 
WHERE event_name = 'video_play'
group by 1, t1.users_view_next_day
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calculating `users_view_videos` and `users_view_next_day`?

Comment: @zealous, I am calculating users_view_videos by "count(users_view_videos)" and for the users_view_next_day, I am calculating by using a lead window function so I can count the next day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a `CTE` which lists all the distinct users who have watched a video on a given day, that can be used to give a count of users who viewed a video on a given day. You can then join it to itself on the condition that the date in the second table is the next day, and the `user_id` is the same, to get the count of those who viewed videos on that day and the next one:

```
WITH viewers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT date, user_id
  FROM clickstream_videos
  WHERE event_name = 'video_play'
)
SELECT v1.date, 
       COUNT(v1.user_id) AS user_view_videos,
       COUNT(v2.user_id) AS users_view_next_day
FROM viewers v1
LEFT JOIN viewers v2 ON v2.date = v1.date + interval '1 day'
                    AND v2.user_id = v1.user_id
GROUP BY v1.date
```

Output:

```
date                        user_view_videos    users_view_next_day
2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    2                   1
2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z    2                   0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/njKt7pjGCm4FkYoQMnV4f7/1)